# Get value from expression in linq extension method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, expression

I searched the whole internet and tried many things, but I am not able to get the value from my expression. It would be very cool if anybody could help me...

bye
Markus

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> GetFilteredByStatusList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, int>> expression)
    {
        // So I can compile the expression.
        // In some posts I have found, that I have to call the compiled method, but the method needs the T object.
        // I have no idea how to acces the value of T.
        Func<T, int> method = expression.Compile();
            //EDIT
            // Here I need the int value to pass it in a service method like:
            // Service.GetStatusById("int value from expression");
            //EDIT END
        return source;
    }
}
```

-- EDIT
I have a query and in this query I have to call a method which needs a dynamic value from the current query item. This method already exists and I get this to work after a the query with a for loop through the query and call this method on every item in this loop. But I think this is not a very fast solution.

So I  to call this method inside the query and that is why I try to implement this with an extension method.

Following the extension method call:

```
return query = query
            .Join(entities.tblTaskgroupGlobal, x => x.lngAssignMain_id, y => y.id, (x, y) => new { x = x, y = y })
            .WhereIf(taskFilterModel.StatusFilterList.Count() > 0, xy => taskFilterModel.StatusFilterList.Contains(xy.y.lngConstantStatus_id))
            .GetFilteredByStatusList(xy => xy.x.lngAssignMain_id)
            .Select(xy => xy.x);
```

-- EDIT END

Comment: the whole internet?! A tip of the hat to you

Comment: I think you need expression trees to parse the shiz.

Comment: @Jonesy except SO ,, in hindi (lakh dukho ki ek dawa he kyun na aajmaye..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, the whole internet! That must have taken a while! :)

The expression you have compiled is now expecting to take an object of type T and return a value of type int.

I would imagine that you want to enumerate `source` and apply your `method` to it.

For example:

```
foreach (T item in source)
{ 
    yield return method(item);
}
```

But I think the better question is - how are you planning to use this method? Are you sure that an Expression is what you need?

Comment: Yes thats right, but i do not know how to access the value of type T from the expression...

Comment: For example, if you have e.g. a list of strings and you call stringList.AsQueryable().GetFilteredByStatusList(s=>s.Count), then in my example, `item` will be each string in the list. YOU determine what the value of T is. T just represents a type, not a concrete object.

Comment: And as a more general recommendation, if you are having trouble implementing a generic method, try creating a non-generic version first, and then change it to be generic once you have it working.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. I edited my post for clarifying the problem. (I hope so...)

Comment: So and now I have understood whats up... Sorry guys, but I thought the  extension method would be called by linq for every item and i have to access it... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be:

return source.Select(expression);

But then again, if that's what you REALLY wanted to do you wouldn't need to write your own `GetFilteredByStatusList` at all.